# How to enforce type on the value that passed to string indexOf?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I do have a const like that

```
const PageType = [
  'type1',
  'type2',
  'type3'
] as const;

export type PageType = typeof PageType[number]
```

say I have a string that I want to check for indexOf `type1`

`mystring.indexOf('type1')` - there is no way I can think how can I enforce the `PageType` here. Say if I misspell the `'type1'` there, I want to see an error, e.g `mystring.indexOf('tpe1')` in that case '`tpe1'` highlighted in IDE

Is there a way to do so in typescript?

Comment: That's _not_ a type problem, you'll get -1 not an error.

Comment: `indexOf` or `includes` when you use them with string are looking for substring also. I believe that TS should not restrict such behaviour

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, I do not mean that I want to see an `indexOf` erroring itself I want to see the `'tpe1'` highlighted as there is no such value in `PageType`.

Comment: @captain-yossarian righ, I just added a bit more details

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see why you think TypeScript would care. `mystring.indexOf('tpe1')` is _not_ a type error. The first argument to `String.prototype.indexOf` is just `string`, and there's no generic type to allow you to say "no but only _these_ strings". If you really want the behaviour "search in a string but for only one of these specific values", write your own function wrapping it.

Comment: Btw, if you call `includes` with `tpe1` on readonly array- it will throw compiler error

Answer (score 0):

This will give the error when you try to assign to const x, below.

```
const PageType = [
    'type1',
    'type2',
    'type3'
  ] as const;
  
  export type PageType = typeof PageType[number]

  const x: PageType = 'tpe1';
```

Comment: And what does this have to do with `.indexOf`?

Comment: If you have the string at compile time, that's a way to make sure you don't have a typo.